# Passing a date through props from UTC to local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-props

I'm trying to pass this `props.data.STDout` which is a string in this format "2022-04-29 14:05:00" from UTC to local time.

I've tried but it doesn't work, do you have any ideas?

```
let newDate = new Date(props.data.STDout);
let newDate2 = newDate.toString()
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `STDout` is a property or a method?

Comment: STDout is a value given by a data base, is a string representing a date on UTC format

Answer (score -1):

Try
`let newDate2 = newDate.toLocaleString()`

Comment: Thanks! 
It works but not as intended. I get the same date but in a different format not having the time difference in to account

from  "2022-04-29 14:05:00" I get 29/4/2022, 14:05:00, and my local time is UTC+2 wich is what I need

Anyway tha nk you very much for your answer :D

Answer (score -1):

I got it!

Just needed to add `UTC` to the original date string, so this is how it looks working perfectly:

```
let newDate = new Date(`${props.data.STDOut} UTC`);
let newDate2 = newDate.toString();
```

As `props.data.STDOut` is a string you should use the literal `` `${}` `` to wrap it and be able to add `UTC` to it, then just parse toString, and done.
It might be a more elegant solution, but for now, if it works, it works.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Produces an invalid date in Safari and Firefox at least. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) If you want to parse it as UTC, change "2022-04-29 14:05:00" to "2022-04-29T14:05:00Z" then pass it to the Date constructor. Or parse it manually by splitting into parts and use `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second))`.

Comment: Hi @RobG, sorry if I didn't explained myself, I needed a UTC date, passed by props as a string parsed to a local date.
But you're right I didn't tried it in other browsers, in Chrome is working, but will check in some other.
Thanks for your answer mate!

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer. Modifying the string as suggested and parsing it with the built–in parser does exactly what you want, i.e. it will parse "2022-04-29 14:05:00" as UTC. You can then get a timestamp in the local timezone with `date.toString()`, or in any timezone with `date.toLocaleString(lang, {timeZone: IANALocation})`.